# Crystal Report Database LogOn when transferred to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

how can i solve this?

when i run my system through my local machine, it does not need any Log On to Database authentication, i can see my reports directly. but when i transferred my system into the server so the others can access it remotly, it requires a logon database and even the information is correct.
here my .cs code

```
public partial class PrintPreview : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ReportDocument crPrint = new ReportDocument();
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["ID"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../Account/LogIn.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            string i = Session["tID"].ToString();

            //CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("../CrystalReport2.rpt");
            crPrint.Load(reportPath);
            crPrint.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Pr0cess", "172.20.3.24", "PO");
            crPrint.SetParameterValue("MOSEFNo", i);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crPrint;
        }



    }


}
```

the page always need the database log on when i transfer it to the database, how come?

and when i transfer the folder to the IIS, the "asp_client" folder is always empty, how do i fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you reload the page the Session["ID"] will be reset to NULL. Try to check your Session State to state server mode.

Comment: hi, my session does not have a problem. it reads my session but it really does not start my crystalreport

Comment: So I think you should create Virtual Directory link to inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\version\crystalreportviewersvesion. First check that exist in you IIS.

Comment: it exists. what more?

Comment: Add Virtual Directory with alias is aspnet_client and physical path with the link in inetpub.

Comment: Does your server credentials differ from the ones used during development? Also, does your report contain any subreports?

Comment: I set full right for IUSR, NetworkService, IIS_IUSRS